# Алгоритм проверки правильности кошелька криптовалюты

Tags: python, алгоритм

Прошу помочь вас с моей проблемкой, сам не справлюсь. Нужно сделать алгоритмы проверки верности введённого кошелька BTC(уже есть), BTG, BCH, ETH, LTC, DASH, DOGE, на python, чистый или с костылями, не волнует. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Вот алгоритм проверки BTC на верность:

```py
def chech_btc(btc):
    if len(btc) > 25 and len(btc) < 36 and (btc[0] == '1' or btc[0] == '3'):
        a = 0
        for i in range(len(btc) - 1):

            if btc[i].isalpha()== True or btc[i].isdigit() == True:
                a = a + 1
        if a == (len(btc) - 1):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: Не ответ, но небольшое замечание по коду. Лучше вместо `0` для "нет", `1` для "да" использовать `False` и `True`.

`== True` во втором блоке `if` также лишнее.

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Узнаём спецификации:

- BTC это строка, начинается с "1" или "3", длинной от 25 до 34. Цифры и буквы без 0 и ещё пары.
- ETH это строка, начинается с "0x", 40 в длину, цифры и строчные буквы от "a" до "f".

*(остальные спецификации узнаются аналогично, через Google)*

Получаем регулярные выражения:

- BTC это `"/^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$"`
- ETH это `"/^(0x)?[0-9a-f]{40}$"`
- ...

*(или пропуская первый шаг, сразу гуглим и находим их [тут](https://www.regextester.com/24))*

Используем примерно так:

```py
def is_btc(source):
    return re.match(r'^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z0-9]{26,33}$', source) is not None

def is_eth(source):
    return re.match(r'^0x[a-fA-F0-9]{40}$', source) is not None
```

PS: Также можно использовать библиотеки для работы с кошельками. Например, для Ethereum:

```py
from ethereum.utils import check_checksum

check_checksum('0xc1912fee45d61c87cc5ea59dae31190fffff232d')
```